# esp8266 set up?

Tags: esp8266

A few weeks ago I was told to incorporate wifi with an arduino project so I ordered a few arduino `ESP8266` boards but when I couldn't figure it out I switched to a simpler board AKA(`Arduino Nano IOT 33`).  Now that I am done with my time constrained project I would like to learn about the `esp8266` can anyone please explain the different settings in the `tools`
See image down below for example.:
[image]